# CSV Text Extraction Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am new to python and this is my first practice code with Beautifulsoup. I have not learned creative solutions to specific data extract problems yet.

This program prints just fine but there is some difficult in extracting to the CSV. It takes the first elements but leaves all others behind. I can only guess there might be some whitespace, delimiter, or something that causes the code to halt extraction after initial texts???

I was trying to get the CSV extraction to happen to each item by row but obviously floundered. Thank you for any help and/or advice you can provide.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv  

price_page = 'http://www.harryrosen.com/footwear/c/boots'
page = urlopen(price_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
product_data = soup.findAll('ul', attrs={'class': 'productInfo'})

for item in product_data:

    brand_name=item.contents[1].text.strip()
    shoe_type=item.contents[3].text.strip()
    shoe_price = item.contents[5].text.strip()
    print (brand_name)
    print (shoe_type)
    print (shoe_price)

with open('shoeprice.csv', 'w') as shoe_prices:
writer = csv.writer(shoe_prices)
writer.writerow([brand_name, shoe_type, shoe_price])
```

Comment: You indentation has challenges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to approach the problem:

- collect the results into a list of dictionaries with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- write the results to a CSV file via the [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and a single `.writerows()` call

The implementation:

```
data = [{
    'brand': item.li.get_text(strip=True),
    'type': item('li')[1].get_text(strip=True),
    'price': item.find('li', class_='price').get_text(strip=True)
} for item in product_data]

with open('shoeprice.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['brand', 'type', 'price'])
    writer.writerows(data)
```

If you want to also write the CSV headers, add the `writer.writeheader()` call before the `writer.writerows(data)`.

Note that you could have as well used the regular `csv.writer` and a list of lists (or tuples), but I like the explicitness and the increased readability of using dictionaries in this case.

Also note that I've improved the locators used in the loop - I don't think using the `.contents` list and getting product children by indexes is a good and reliable idea.

Comment: Thank you for the solution alecxe! I will go forward with your suggestion on the use of .contents and learn more about formatting data.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('shoeprice.csv', 'w') as shoe_prices:
    writer = csv.writer(shoe_prices)
    for item in product_data:
        brand_name=item.contents[1].text.strip()
        shoe_type=item.contents[3].text.strip()
        shoe_price = item.contents[5].text.strip()
        print (brand_name, shoe_type, shoe_price, spe='\n')

        writer.writerow([brand_name, shoe_type, shoe_price])
```

Change the open file to the outer loop, so you do not need to open file each loop.

Comment: Thank you for the help宏杰李! This is another way that is very useful to know.